# Post a photo in FB with GraphAPI in Python

Tags: python, image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

Right now my job is advertise different kinds of business.
In order to do that i need to post in multiple facebook groups different products but that eats pretty much all my time so i'm trying to develop my own post-bot so i can post whatever i want in the moment in all the specific local facebook groups immediately.

I can post text in the feed, but can't make the code post a picture with text.
I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Ventas\Desktop\Post2.py", line 31, in 
>       graph.put_object(parent_object=group_id, connection_name='photos', caption=titulo, message=mensaje, source=foto)   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facebook__init__.py", line 144, in
>   put_object
>       method="POST")   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facebook__init__.py", line 272, in
>   request
>       raise GraphAPIError(result) GraphAPIError: (#324) Requires upload file

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, this is my code:

```
#SETUP Photo with file selection dialog
Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
dir = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
photo = open(dir, "rb").read()

#POST IN GROUPS
for group_id in groups:
    print("Posting to " + 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/' + str(group_id))
    graph.put_object(parent_object=group_id, connection_name='photos', caption=titulo, message=mensaje, source=photo)
```

Comment: Take in mind this is my first time using Python. 
I have used other programming languages before, but i'm a novice in Python, just started using it and learning it yesterday so i might not understand everything. 

Regards and thank you all beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i tried selenium, something that a guy on facebook recommended me, but it did not worked, so i went back to python.
I was playing around with the api, but the documentation was not very clear in how to post in a group specifically. 
So i started surfing the most deep part in google and found **[THIS](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/facebook-sdk/latest/facebook-sdk.pdf)**

It made me reach to the conclusion of the code, the freakin' solution! :D (OMG FINALLY) i've been working on this thing like 4 days already.

I just changed this:

```
graph.put_object(parent_object=group_id, connection_name='photos', caption=titulo, message=mensaje, source=photo)
```

To this:

```
graph.put_photo(image=photo, message=mensaje, album_path=group_id + "/photos")
```

Also i noticed that the original documentation says that the value "album_path" should be:

```
album_path=group_id + "/pictures"
```

But thats ONLY and STRICTLY for pages.
It seems that for groups is:

```
album_path=group_id + "/photos"
```

Thank you to anyone who bothered to at least read my question, and very special thanks to the users "Jérémy de Gail" and "Amit Singh" from facebook, since no one bothered to even try to help me. 
This code is very important for my job.

Hope my own answer may help someone in the future.
Regards to everyone! :D

Comment: I post the group and got this error `(#120) Invalid album id`

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the picture in the same file where you have your .py script.
Then, do:

```
photo = "nameofyourpic.jpg"
```

Instead of:

```
photo = open(dir, "rb").read()
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for answering.
But it didn't worked, the same error appears in the console.

Answer (score 0):

As of the new API release, you can no longer upload images through a local path but rather a relative URL (Image stored on server).

```
graph.put_object(parent_object=group_id, connection_name='photos', caption=titulo, message=mensaje, source="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-VqCH72pVnok/X-WgDpD5jSI/AAAAAAAA20E/pLCoCXR_7tsme8etcjYAOJhNa9GdPh4ewCLcBGAsYHQ/w640-h428/iherb_holiday.png")
```